# Promise.any is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use a library with Angular, which uses Promise.any. When calling a function there, I get the error `TypeError: Promise.any is not a function`. The library has a React example, which works for me in the same browser. Afaik, Promise.any is not finalized in the specification yet, so it's not available in ES2020.

How can I configure Angular to use ESNext? I tried setting `target`, `module` and `lib` to `"ESNext"` in `tsconfig.json` but that does not work.

Comment: To use non-core-Javascript features, you need a compiler like Babel to compile the missing Promise.any into code that standard runtimes accept.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to `npm i -s core-js` and add `import 'core-js/features/promise';` to `src/polyfills.ts` to add support for Promise.any